# Kafka compression on Broker side

Tags: apache-kafka, compression, confluent-platform, confluent-cloud

There are settings to enable compression per Producer and per Topic.
But i also heard about global setting - Broker side compression (for all topics), is it real ?
If so how to configure ? Any link ?